# Do not see changes made in HTML file in Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I have created simple login.html file in Dynamic Web Project + Maven + GlassFish in Eclipse.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       form {text-align: center}
    </style>
 </head>
<body>  
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        USERNAME:<input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br>
        PASSWORD:<input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="ENTER"/>
        <input type="reset" value="CLEAR"/>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I launch login.html file like Run as -> Run on server and it looks ok.
But when I changed something in html and try to run it on server I did not see my changes.
Try mvn clean, mvn install.
What should I do to see changes in html file when I Run it on Server?  (In Preview I see changes)

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your *.html file on server it opens in Eclipse browser. To see your changes you need to click on Green triangle "Go to the selected URL" and page will be updated.